# Change the SuperUser Advertising Info link to point to a Super User page

Tags: feature-request, advertising

I recently followed the **advertising info** link from SuperUser (in the page footer), it takes you to the [same page](http://inedomedia.com/stackoverflow.aspx) as for StackOverflow. This page states it is possible to sponsor specific tags, which is only possible on StackOverflow (established over an email exchange with the nice people at Inedo Media).

I suggest to avoid confusion it would make sense to have a separate page for each site, if only because following an advertising link from SuperUser (or ServerFault) shouldn't take you to a StackOverflow-branded page.

Answer (score 2):

Good idea, we'll follow up on this!

Comment: If you decide to update it, perhaps you can you clarify the wording to indicate what type of ads are supported on each site (as in this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32042)