# Allow for sponsored tags on SuperUser

Tags: support, advertising

I recently enquired about advertising my StackExchange site on specific tags on SuperUser. I was informed that tag-targeted ads are only supported on StackOverflow.

There are a small set of around 20 tags on SuperUser that overlap with my site, ideally I'd like to target these tags to maximise my limited advertising budget.

Is this limitation a technical or financial decision? Will it be possible to target tags on SuperUser if/when it reaches a high enough volume?

Comment: I would also like to target the `android` tag on SuperUser for my site http://www.forceclose.com/ - but the volume is so low it would not be very effective.

Comment: +1 I like the idea.  If this happens, can I call first-dibs on "money", "money-management", "quicken", etc.? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a technical limitation, more a practical one. Advertising is a numbers game, and you need a good number of impressions (100K+) over a month to really have an impact.

Most of the tags on Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault simply do not have enough questions to provide for this type of traffic.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But I'm not Adobe, a big impact for my site would be 10 new regular users and a few more questions. My tiny budget would probably be better spent targeting the tags relevant to my site even if that is low impact. I suspect a lot of StackExchange sites are in the same boat. From your perspective does it matter if the adverts run for a few days or a few months to get the 100k views?

Comment: We work very hard to make sure that ad campaigns are successful by monitoring performance, tweaking (keywords, creatives, etc), tracking conversions, having recurring conversations with clients, etc; as such, it's not practical for us to do really small campaigns, and we don't want to segment by offering different levels of service. But... a few hundred bucks on AdWords can go a long way.

Comment: thanks for the update. I'll explore my options a bit more

Answer (score 2):

You can contact our ad sales weasels by clicking the "advertising info" link at the bottom of the page -- I'm sure they'll be happy to help you out!

Comment: I did that, a nice weasel called Bill told me that tag-targeted ads aren't supported on SuperUser.

Comment: LOL.  I'm cracking up!  Bill was pleasant to deal with, yes :-)

Comment: Yes he was pleasant to deal with, I'm just using Jeff's terminology

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have though that this is due to a technical reason as the svn revision numbers of both sites are currently the same at 5751.

Additionally, I have seen some StackExchange sites that have tags with logos on them that (as has been mentioned in other threads on here) are older/different branches of the main SO source.

Comment: The SE sites are using various jQuery/CSS hacks to add logos to tags, that's how I do it on mine.

Comment: I'm using the same method as Rich to add logos to tags at my StackExchange site.