# Report ad feature needed

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, advertising

After two [recent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38528/getting-rid-of-advertisements-that-directly-resemble-so-styles) [incidents](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35264/should-ads-that-mimic-stackoverflow-ui-be-allowed) of advertisers using fake UI in ads do we need a way to report ads that's quicker than raising the issue on meta?

Since ads are seen more by newer users we can't rely on long time users to report them before the advertisers have benefited from them; so a way for users to directly report ads would mean they spend much less time up on the site. Ideally I'd like to make it so that advertisers realise that trying to game Stack Overflow is counter-productive.

I think facebook has a good implementation of this:
[alt text http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/3422/facebookads.png](http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/3422/facebookads.png)

Note that you can remove the ad by clicking the 'x' (replacing it with a new one, or eventually a "Find your Gmail friends" message that can't be removed) and there are several reasons you can report the ad for. There is also a "like" feature, which might provide useful stats to advertisers.

It might also be useful to have a [Sponsor Gallery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14716/sponsor-gallery-page-or-something-like-that) so that everyone can see what ads are appearing on the site.

Comment: This is not trivial to implement, and doing all of this because of just two incidents is overkill. People can just report them here, it works. Also jeff states that he'd talk to the ad team so it's unlikely to happen again.

Comment: This is really all a conspiracy to get a Facebook feature implemented on Stack Overflow.

Comment: A bet, for sure :)

Comment: For future reference: instructions were provided in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85932/how-do-i-report-an-advertisement-seen-on-a-stackexchange-site-as-offensive/85935#85935) on how to report ads to the Ads Team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we just need all the ads to be visually approved by us before they go in.