# How do I report an advertisement seen on a StackExchange site as offensive?

Tags: feature-request, support, advertising, offensive, flags

I was browsing stackoverflow.com and one the advertisements displayed on the right hand side I found to be particularly offensive.

I've already written a complaint to the company who the advertisement was for, but I was wondering if there was a way I could report it to the maintainers of stackoverflow.com?

Thanks,

Comment: Do share with us. We want to know who was offensive. Pretty pretty please.

Comment: Let me guess. It was the ladybug being murdered. We get that a lot.

Comment: In the interest of keeping this question on-topic, I'm not going to, sorry :P

Comment: Actually .... In the interest of keeping the question on-topic is why I asked. There's very *very* **very** little around here that's private. The site was designed that way. But I can understand about you don't want to offend other people. But the more eyeballs that see it the more that *the community* can make their own decisions, ya see. If lots and lots of people object to something, that's more information for team@ to make a decision with. Also, public shame is an AMAZING motivator.

Comment: If my original question was a discussion on whether or not the community found it offensive, then sure. But it was just a simple question about how to report offensive ads. If you **really** want to have a discussion about it, I can start a new question, but then it kinda leaves the realm of "meta-StackExchange" questions and is more a general discussion, don't you think? But then again, if `meta` is a place for that then I guess it's okay.

Comment: @tokes: +1 Good question. I think I had also found that to be some how... inappropriate

Comment: I WANT TO SEE THE AD.  NOW.

Comment: @Will: I think it's http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7c324aed4f4f4cb6a09512626ec05838.jpg

Comment: @Will: Funny, but what's the relation between a woman's breasts starring four men with Data Validation and Certification Server?

Comment: @Will: thanks for proving my point. Had I linked to the ad in question originally, this question would be filled with useless comments such as yours, which do nothing to answer the question I actually posed (which is relevant regardless of what actual ad I saw in that instance), and only show off narrow-mindedness. So much for being a member of a community focused around intelligent discussion and sharing of knowledge.

Comment: @tokes: The ease with which you become offended and the joy you take in abusing others as a consequence and the self-righteous smug satisfaction you take in being superior to us low-brows doesn't do much for my opinion of you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the bottom of the page you will find two links that may prove of interest, one labeled "contact us" which gives you an email that goes directly to Stack Exchange, and another provides a link to "advertising info", which gives both an email and a phone contact for the advertising department in particular.

Comment: Please consider sending a screenshot, describing the ad in detail, and providing a link to the image and/or the target of the ad so they know for certain which ad is the problem.  In some cases they may be running several ads for a given client, and it can be hard to tell which one you're talking about if you only say, "It's that one that mentions Visual Studio."

Comment: I closed the tab the page was on, but luckily I refreshed a few times and the same ad re-appeared ;)

Answer (score 4):

Posting here is a good start, but e-mail team@stackoverflow.com. There's a link at the foot of every page.

Don't forget to include all the details of the ad.