# Advertisements too close to content, disagreeable and simply poor interface design

Tags: feature-request, advertising, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should ads that mimic StackOverflow UI be allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35264/should-ads-that-mimic-stackoverflow-ui-be-allowed)

Steve Krug's famous statement when it comes to interface design is: Don't Make Me Think. What got me thinking about Stack Overflow's design is those pesky and annoying advertisements  interspersed with genuine content.

Here's my beef in a nutshell: I don't care where programmers ask business questions, and I don't want that stupid blue advertising text interrupting the flow of a real Stack Overflow discussion. Is it possible to change its placement or change its design so it looks less like part of the content?

I'm not objecting to advertisements. It's just that in this case they are very poorly integrated into the interface. They actually detract from the usability of the content that all the great programmer/writers generously provide. And it's that content that is the reason for many of us to visit, read, and contribute. Please rethink the way advertisements are integrated, and thank you thank you for a great resource.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35264/should-ads-that-mimic-stackoverflow-ui-be-allowed

Comment: Beef in a nutshell?

Comment: *It's just that in this case they are very poorly integrated into the interface.* Rather they are too well integrated into the interface, and makes your brain take notice of it. That is what ads are supposed to be doing. It's not so bad, it conveys the information of where you are going to if you click it and it's placed where all the other ads are. If you really hate it, either get Ad-Block or get over 200 rep points, which disables those ads.